# How to remove permission sets from a package

Tags: managed-package, app-development, permissions, user-management

We created some permission sets to include with our managed package. However, we have now realized that it isn't the best approach since not all orgs can use permission sets.

However, we cannot find anyway to removed the permission sets from the package...is this possible? There doesn't seem to be any option available from within the create -> package UI or the manager users -> permission sets UI.

EDIT: You have an option to delete the Perm Set on the Perm Set page. However, since this is part of the package (I think). You get this error:

> Cannot delete last list view. You can't delete the last list view
>   that's Visible to all users or Visible to certain groups of users.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**It can't be done.** I've had the same problem, your best bet is to start a new managed package.

However, if your App is uploaded to the AppExchange, and your a partner, you can try to contact Salesforce partner support (if your a partner and it is distributed on the AppExchange). Ask them to 'unlock' your package, you will have to have it uninstalled from all orgs where it has been installed.

PS. Oddly enough our package installed into edition that would otherwise not support permission sets, but than it wouldn't uninstall. "Uninstall Button" just disappeared and than it hung after you hit uninstall and never completely uninstalled.

Answer (score 1):

Some managed components are not deletable.

Check the Package Publishing guide on Developer.force.com for more information on the different behaviors of managed components:

- [ISVforce Guide: Components Available in Managed Packages](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/packaging_packageable_components.htm)